# PHP: Get multiple Strings between

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I have the following string:

```
$string = '"https://i.stack.imgur.com/?oapQok.png" blabla "https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9*xp.png" blabla "https://i.stack.imgur.com/papsyewxp.jpg"'
```

I now want to get the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => string("?oapQok.png")
  [1] => string("p9*xp.png")
  [2] => string("papsyewxp.jpg")
}
```

The problem: The length varies, there are 'strange' --> *$? chars in it, etc...

Can you explain how to fix it?

Comment: Are all the URLs are double quoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [following regular expression](http://rubular.com/r/UmusQS01Zc):

```
"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/([^"]+)"
```

Also see the php documentation on [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to pull out the captures.

Comment: This will have some false positive matches -- it will match "http://i.imgur.com/" i.e. no foo.png.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks. Updated to match at least one character after the slash.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '"https://i.stack.imgur.com/?oapQok.png" blabla "https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9*xp.png" blabla "https://i.stack.imgur.com/papsyewxp.jpg"';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```